# Deprecated Reflection constructor

Tags: java, reflections

I am running sonar cloud through my Java code and it has some deprecated constructors. I managed to update most of them, but not this one:

```
import org.reflections.util.ClasspathHelper;

private static final String PACKAGE_ENTITIES = "my.package";

new Reflections(PACKAGE_ENTITIES, new SubTypesScanner(false), ClasspathHelper.forClassLoader());
```

`'org.reflections.scanners.SubTypesScanner' is deprecated` is the official sonar message.

My guess is `Scanners.SubTypes (s -> true)`

Any tips?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Check the [documentation of the `SubTypesScanner` class](https://ronmamo.github.io/reflections/org/reflections/scanners/SubTypesScanner.html):

> **Deprecated.**
>
> scan superclass and interfaces of a class, allowing a reverse lookup for subtypes. *Deprecated, use [`Scanners.SubTypes`](https://ronmamo.github.io/reflections/org/reflections/scanners/Scanners.html#SubTypes) instead*

So the solution is to use the [`Scanners.SubTypes`](https://ronmamo.github.io/reflections/org/reflections/scanners/Scanners.html#SubTypes) field instead.